# Grouping data in specific way

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am building report which shows the parts of one work order in different departments.
Consider the table below

```
work_order  part  dept_code  datein
aaaa        11    XXX        20/01/2017
aaaa        12    BBB        22/01/2017
bbbb        12    XXX        20/01/2017
bbbb        15    XXX        22/01/2017
cccc        13    XXX        20/01/2017
cccc        17    XYX        20/01/2017
```

Now i want to group this data in such way that only the work order with different dept_code should show up. 
RESULT

```
work_order  part  dept_code  datein
aaaa        11    XXX        20/01/2017
aaaa        12    BBB        22/01/2017
cccc        13    XXX        20/01/2017
cccc        17    XYX        20/01/2017
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a subquery that identifies those `work_order` items which's department-count is greater than 1:

```
select * from work
where work_order in
  (select work_order
   from work w2
   group by w2.work_order
   having count(w2.dept_code) > 1
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
SELECT work_order, part, dept_code, datein
FROM [Table]
WHERE work_order in
(
    SELECT work_order
    FROM [Table]
    GROUP BY work_order
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT dept_code) > 1
)
```

Comment: Why use `distinct work_order`? `GROUP BY work_order` will anyway produce unique work_orders, not?

Answer (score 2):

you can use count() over() as below:

```
Select * from (
   Select *, cnt = Count(dept_code) over(partition by work_order, dept_code) from yourTable   ) a
   Where a.cnt = 1
```